# Incremental search line highlight

Tags: hooks, highlighting, isearch, hl-line-mode

When running incremental search by pressing `C-s` repeatedly (`isearch-repeat-forward`) is there a way to highlight, in addition to the matching string, the line where that string is found?

I would like to get an effect equivalent to the one shown below (obtained using `swiper` and searching the string "dict"), where both the matching string and the entire line are clearly visible.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways I can think of:

1. Turn on `hl-line-mode`. This just always highlights the current line.
2. Put the function you use to highlight the current line on `isearch-update-post-hook`.    You can use this if you don't want to use `hl-line-mode`.

```lisp
(add-hook 'isearch-update-post-hook 'my-highlight-current-line)
```

3. Have `hl-line-mode` be turned on only for isearch, by using hooks `isearch-mode-hook` and `isearch-mode-end-hook`:

```lisp
(defun turn-off-hl-line-mode () (hl-line-mode -1))

(add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook 'hl-line-mode)
(add-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook 'turn-off-hl-line-mode)
```

Comment: Thank you; very straightforward answer. I opted for number 3. 
To make it work I had to modify it slightly, ```(add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook (apply-partially #'hl-line-mode +1))
(add-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook (apply-partially #'hl-line-mode -1))```, as the ```isearch-mode-end-hook``` was being ignored, possibly because it was activating ```hl-line-mode``` again instead of setting it off.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've updated the answer wrt `isearch-mode-end-hook`. Thx.